# Phalcon hasManyToMany data load very slow

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a problem with load slow dates from model with hasManyToMany.

I have code:

```
class TvguideChannel extends Model{

public function initialize() {
    $this->setSource('tvguide_channel');
    $this->setConnectionService('db');

    $this->hasManyToMany(
        'code', 
        __NAMESPACE__.'\Tvguide', 
        "ch_code",
        'ch_code', 
        __NAMESPACE__.'\Chgrtv', 
        'ch_code',
        ['alias' => 'tvguide']
    );
    //$this->hasMany('code', __NAMESPACE__.'\Chgrtv', 'ch_code', ['alias' => 'tvgg']);
}

  public function getSource() {
    return 'tvguide_channel';
  }
}
```

Table Tvguide have more records (1kk+), but TvguideChannel have 228 records

When I Want output records from table TvguideChannel with:

```
$data = TvguideChannel::find();
```

I get load page more 5 seconds.
How I can output all records correctly with relation hasManyToMany?

Comment: Are your tables indexed?

Comment: Yes of course!!

Comment: Related models are lazy loaded.  They're not actually queried for until your code asks for them.  So setting up a relationship doesn't mean all those related records are pulled.  I'd be surprised if the page load time decreases if you remove that relationship.  Have you wrapped `TvguideChannel::find()` in `microtime()` to see if that's causing the delay?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using eager loading instead. The incubator allow this, just include it into your project and use the "with" instead of "find".

```
composer require phalcon/incubator
```

https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/Model

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\EagerLoading\Loader,
    Phalcon\Mvc\Model\EagerLoading\QueryBuilder;

$robotsAndParts = Robot::with('Parts');

// Equivalent to:

$robots = Robot::find();
foreach ($robots as $robot) {
    $robot->parts; // $robot->__get('parts')
}

// Or

$robot = Robot::findFirst()->load('Parts');

// Equivalent to:

$robot = Robot::findFirst();
$robots->parts; // $robot->__get('parts')

// Because Robot::find() returns a resultset, so in that case this is solved with:
$robots = Loader::fromResultset(Robot::find(), 'Parts'); # Equivalent to the second example

// Multiple and nested relations can be used too
$robots = Robot::with('Parts', 'Foo.Bar');

// And arguments can be passed to the find method
$robots = Robot::with('Parts', 'Foo.Bar', ['limit' => 5]);

// And constraints
$robots = Robot::with(
    [
        'Parts',
        'Foo.Bar' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
            // Limit Bar
            $builder->limit(5);
        }
    ],
    [
        'limit' => 5
    ]
);
```

Distributed as single package at https://github.com/stibiumz/phalcon.eager-loading